# Eclipse OwnerDrawLabelProvider makes selection background dark blue

Tags: swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

I'm currently developing an Eclipse RCP application, and am in need of using an [OwnerDrawLabelProvider](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fjface%2Fviewers%2FOwnerDrawLabelProvider.html) as a `CellLabelProvider` for a `TableViewerColumn`
This is because when I use any other `CellLabelProvider`, the Image used is not centered.

**My problem** is that when the row is selected, the background of the cell that has this provider is of a darker blue than all the other cells.

This is how the "selected" state looks:

[image]

Here's my OwnerDrawLabelProvider:

```java
class SomeLabelProvider extends OwnerDrawLabelProvider {
            private static final int smallColumnSize = 70;

            @Override
            protected void measure( Event event, Object element ) {
                Rectangle rectangle = IMAGE_CHECKED.getBounds();
                event.setBounds( new Rectangle( event.x, event.y, smallColumnSize, 
                                                              rectangle.height ) );
            }

            @Override
            protected void paint( Event event, Object element ) {
                Rectangle bounds = event.getBounds();
                //paint icon at the center
                event.gc.drawImage( getImage( element ),
                                    bounds.x + ((smallColumnSize - 
                                    IMAGE_CHECKED.getBounds().width) / 2),
                                    bounds.y );
            }

            //this is implemented somewhere else
            protected abstract Image getImage( Object element );

        }
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is caused by the default `erase` method, the JavaDoc for this says:

> Handle the erase event. The default implementation colors the
>   background of selected areas with SWT.COLOR_LIST_SELECTION and
>   foregrounds with SWT.COLOR_LIST_SELECTION_TEXT. Note that this
>   implementation causes non-native behavior on some platforms.
>   Subclasses should override this method and not call the super
>   implementation.

So just add an `erase` override which does nothing:

```java
@Override
protected void erase(Event event, Object element) 
{
  // Don't call super to avoid selection draw
}
```